# How to unit test Android ConnectivityManager

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito, android-connectivitymanager

I am building an application by which we can detect the availability of internet connection using `ConnectivityManager` class but I am not sure how to add unit test for this using `Mockito`. Please help me writing the unit test case for the following code:

```
class ConnectivityMgr @Inject constructor(val context: Context) {
    fun isConnectedOrConnecting(): Boolean {
        val connMgr = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            connMgr.getNetworkCapabilities(connMgr.activeNetwork)?.run {
                return hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) || hasTransport(
                    NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR
                )
            }
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            connMgr.activeNetworkInfo?.let {
                return when (it.type) {
                    ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI -> true
                    ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE -> true
                    else -> false
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use Roboelectric to test your `ConnectivityMgr` class. A sample test  when the device is connected to WiFi would be like this:

```
fun `should be connected when connected to WiFi`() {
    val connectivityManager = getApplicationContext<Context>().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    val networkCapabilities = ShadowNetworkCapabilities.newInstance()
    shadowOf(networkCapabilities).addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
    shadowOf(connectivityManager).setNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork, networkCapabilities)

    assertTrue(connectivityMgr.isConnectedOrConnecting())
}
```

Roboelectric provides [`ShadowNetworkCapabilities`](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/4.3/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowNetworkCapabilities.html) for fetching and updating transport.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh but doing that I am getting the following exception :

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowNetworkCapabilities

Comment: Maybe try annotating your test method with `@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.Q])`

Comment: I tried the following but assertion always returns false.

    ```@Test
    @Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.P])```

Comment: I was missing the context. Thanks Saurabh for the help.

Comment: @Adhish how did you solve that classCastException ? I am getting the same.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue. Any luck?